# Qt QTcpSocket doesn't emit signal when reading data

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, signals, slot

I need to update the content of a chat window when it receives a message. Here are the two functions I use  :

```
void LinPop::_createChat(Client *socket)
{
    ChatDialog *chat = new ChatDialog();

    chat->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    qDebug() << "Connecting chat : ";
    qDebug() << connect(chat, SIGNAL(toSend(QString&)), socket, SLOT(send(QString&)));
    qDebug() << connect(socket, SIGNAL(gotTexted(QString)), chat, SLOT(updateChat(QString)));
    chat->exec();
}
```

This is the slot that is called when the socket has something to read. It works fine, except the signal either isn't emitted or the connected slot isn't called.

```
void Client::readyRead()
{
    if (this->_socket->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        QByteArray data = this->_socket->readAll();
        QString text(data);

        emit gotTexted(text);
        qDebug() << "ReadyRead [" << text << "] [" << this->_socket->bytesAvailable() << "]";
    }
}
```

Console output :

```
Connecting chat :  
true 
true 
Sent [ "Test" ] 
ReadyRead [ "Test" ] [ 0 ]
```

Now, if I do this, it goes into an infinite loop but suddenly the signal/slot thing works just fine and my text gets sent to the chat window and displayed :

```
void Client::readyRead()
{
    if (this->_socket->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        QByteArray data = this->_socket->readAll();
        QString text(data);
        this->_socket->write(data); // Added this

        emit gotTexted(text);
        qDebug() << "ReadyRead [" << text << "] [" << this->_socket->bytesAvailable() << "]";
    }
}
```

Console output :

```
Connecting chat :  
true 
true 
Sent [ "Test" ] 
ReadyRead [ "Test" ] [ 0 ] 
Update Chat [ "Test" ] 
ReadyRead [ "Test" ] [ 0 ]
// Infinite Loop
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work in the first place or why, when I turn it into an infinite loop, it suddenly starts working...

PS : Here is the updateChat slot :

```
void ChatDialog::updateChat(QString text)
{
    this->ui->tbConv->insertPlainText(text);
    qDebug() << "Update Chat [" << text << "]";
}
```

Comment: which signal are you expecting from QtcpSocket?

Comment: Could you provide a short, compilable example?

Answer (score 0):

How do you perform socket connection? I cant get code responsible for listening for connection. If you dont have any other tcp client try with telnet